# OSX Terminal Can't Type the Letter "B"

Tags: macos, keyboard, terminal

This is a weird one.

On Mountain Lion my terminal will not allow me to type the letter 'B' (lower or upper). When I hit the 'b' key I get the warning 'bonk' sound from OSX. The 'b' key still works just find in everything else. It's only messed up in Terminal.

This is driving me nuts.

Comment: That isn't a programming question; try http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks trojanfoe - I didn't even know that site existed. Found my solution here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39696/why-does-terminal-ignore-capital-b